# Matlab - how to read a file with a large number of integer columns using textscan

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I have a file which contains data in the following format:

```
filename.jpg,132,234,234,345,4555,23333,344,...,333
```

I have put `...` to mark the fact that I have a long sequence of integers. On each line I have a total of 132 integers.

I want to read the numbers in a matrix with `132` columns and as many rows as I have in the input file. How can I read this data with `textscan` function? How should I specify this type of format? I also want to read the first column of filenames into a cell array.

For the cell array I have used the following syntax:

```
fid = fopen(inputPath);
buffer = textscan(fid, '%s%*[^\n]', 'Delimiter', ',');

close(fid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow your first call to `textscan` with a `csvread` instead:

```
A = csvread('data.txt', 0, 1);
```

The two last parameters specify row and column at which your data starts. Your cell will contain the strings from the first column, `A` contains a matrix with the data.

Otherwise, if you really have to use `textscan`, create your format string aside:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
% crate a string with as many %f as you need
fmt = ['%s' repmat('%f', 1, 132)];
buffer = textscan(fid, fmt, 'Delimiter', ',');
names = buffer{1};
A = [buffer{2:end}];
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: When I try to use csvread I receive the following error:                Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 2u) ==>
_01_01_041_00.png,345,211,406,206,393,239,370,285,411,280,331,300,429,279,343,313,421,296,360,325,412,314,394,326,320,203,358,194,397,190,418,191,338,196,408,189,328,198,348,193,403,190,413,190,381,20

Error in csvread (line 48)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);

Comment: @Simon well, use it as I have - with two additional parameters.